# Why I get X.map() is not a function in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary

I have a problem list table with reactjs I have one worked code and not worked part.
I want take datas from api and add an array for listing component the componetns are already designed and it has props are all true.

Let me explain:

Code Snippet:

```
import './App.css';
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {Container, Row} from 'reactstrap';
import Login from './components/Login';

import MainPage from './MainPage';
import WorkersPage from './WorkersPage';
import Schedule from './components/Schedule';
import Createrequest from './components/Createrequest';
import Jobrequests from './components/Jobrequests';




function getLocalObject(y)
{
  var x;
  x=localStorage.getItem(y);
  return JSON.parse(x);

}

let array=[]
let requestArray=[]

function App() {
  const [profile,setProfile]=useState('');
  const [username,setUsername]=useState('');
  const [requestedJobName,setRequestedJobName]=useState('');
  const [requests,setRequests]=useState([]); //this is for requests
  const [message,setMessage]=useState('')
  const [password,setPassword]=useState('');
  const [logout,setLogout]=useState(0);
  const [allJobs,setAllJobs]=useState([]);  //this is for all jobs
  
//This is for all jobs
  useEffect(() => {
    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      redirect: 'follow'
    };

   
    
    fetch("http://localhost/scheduleapp/api/schedule/all", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => {
          setAllJobs(JSON.parse(result))
          console.log('rs',result,'ls',allJobs)
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    
  }, [])

 // This is for requests (only admins!)
  useEffect(() => {
    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      redirect: 'follow'
    };
    
    fetch("http://localhost/scheduleapp/api/schedule/admin/requests", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => {setRequests( JSON.parse(result))})
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

  }, [])

  
 

 
  function exit()
{
  localStorage.clear()
  window.location.reload(true);
}
   //login function
  const login = () => {
    
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    myHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');
    var raw = JSON.stringify({username, password});
    
    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: raw,
      redirect: 'follow'
    };
    //dsaasd
    fetch("http://localhost/scheduleapp/api/personals/login", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data =>{
        localStorage.setItem('Logged',data);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
      
      window.location.reload();

  }

   if(!getLocalObject('Logged'))
   {


     return(  <div> <Login onSubmit={(e)=>e.preventDefault(e)} username={(e)=>setUsername(e.target.value)} password={(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)} OnClick={()=>login()  } /></div> 
    
     )
   }
   else{
    

 

    if(getLocalObject('Logged').is_admin==1)
    {
  
   
      function accept()
      {

      }
      function decline()
      {
        
      }
  

      return (
          

        <div>
          {allJobs.map(item=>{
         
          return (<Schedule  approved_job_name={item.approved_job_name} approved_job_unique_id={item.approved_job_unique_id} approved_job_worker={item.approved_job_worker} date={item.date} />
                   
            )//it works great

        }   )
        
        

        }
        {
                 requests.map( item=>{
                  return(
                  <Jobrequests id={item.id}/>
                
                  )// this gives 'TypeError: requests.map is not a function'


                  
        
              } )
         
        }
        

       


          
        
          
           <button onClick={exit} className='btn btn-danger'>LogOut</button>  
      </div>
      );

    }
    else{

      function sendRequest()
      {

        var myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        
        var raw = JSON.stringify({
          "requestedJobName":  requestedJobName,
          "uniquejobid": requestedJobName+Date.now(),
          "username": getLocalObject('Logged').username
        });
        
        var requestOptions = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: myHeaders,
          body: raw,
          redirect: 'follow'
        };
        
        fetch("http://localhost/scheduleapp/api/schedule/worker/addrequest", requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(result => console.log(result))
          .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
      }
      return (
          



        <div className='ms-4 mt-4'>
          <Createrequest onSubmit={(e)=>e.preventDefault()} onChange={(e)=>setRequestedJobName(e.target.value)} onClick={sendRequest} />
          {allJobs.map(item=>{
            return (
              <Schedule  approved_job_name={item.approved_job_name} approved_job_unique_id={item.approved_job_unique_id} approved_job_worker={item.approved_job_worker} date={item.date} />

            )

          })}

            


    

           

          <button onClick={exit} className='btn btn-danger'>LogOut</button>
        </div>
      );
    }


   
   }

  
}

export default App;
```

I want if logged user is admin user will see job requests and all jobs all jobs is listed success but requests give error "map is not a function"
Best Regards
Thanks from now...

**Edit:**
Console Log Outputs:

> useEffect(() => {
> fetch("http://localhost/scheduleapp/api/schedule/admin/requests")
> .then(response => setRequests(response.json()))
>
> }, [])

Output:
req []

> useEffect(() => {
> fetch("http://localhost/scheduleapp/api/schedule/admin/requests")
> .then(response => setRequests(response.json()))
> }, [])

```
 Output:
    req 
    Promise {<fulfilled>: {…}}
    [[Prototype]]: Promise
    [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
    [[PromiseResult]]: Object
    id: "1"
    request_job_current_date: "2021-10-05"
    request_job_name: "sdasdads"
    request_job_unique_id: "sdasdads1633453239"
    request_job_worker_uname: "dariustheone"
    [[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: what line is producing the error?

Comment: Please format your code to make it somewhat readable and remove unrelated code.

Answer (score 0):

Since `requests` initial state is an array and that there is only one `setRequest`, your problem is coming from the data your are passing to

```
.then(result => {setRequests( JSON.parse(result))})
```

Check what's in `result` and also it's quite weird that you call .text() instead of .json() since you use JSON.parse.

But anyway your problem is coming from the content of `result` which doesn't seem to be an array

Comment: I added           {console.log('req',requests)} and the console output is  
 req 
{id: '1', request_job_name: 'sdasdads', request_job_unique_id: 'sdasdads1633453239', request_job_worker_uname: 'dariustheone', request_job_current_date: '2021-10-05'}
id: "1"
request_job_current_date: "2021-10-05"
request_job_name: "sdasdads"
request_job_unique_id: "sdasdads1633453239"
request_job_worker_uname: "dariustheone"
[[Prototype]]: Object   but when I want to put screen it doesnt work

Comment: it's hard to read but it seems you are getting an Object and not an array ?

Comment: you can't map on object in javascript

Comment: Can I list object list another functions?

Comment: if. you don't get an array why do you need to use .map in first place ? why not doing requests.id directly ?

Comment: There a lot of objects I want listed the objects under of a table

Comment: as I said requests doesn't seem to be un array [] but un object {}, I don't understand your data structure please clarify in your question

Comment: @OĞUZHANŞENOKUR Could you add the console result to the question and decently format it?

Comment: @3limin4t0r sure

Comment: @OĞUZHANŞENOKUR It seems like your response is indeed a single request, like François Richard already suggested. You have 2 options here. 1) Change the server code and make sure that `http://localhost/scheduleapp/api/schedule/admin/requests` always returns an array. 2) Change the client code so that the returned object is placed inside an array if it isn't already. `.then(response => response.json()).then(requests => Array.isArray(requests) ? requests : Array.of(requests)).then(setRequests)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make sure that the fetch request to '/scheduleapp/api/schedule/admin/requests' return an array after you parse it. The error happen when you try to map something that is not an array.

Comment: hi can you send me pm message I need help about this really

Answer (score 0):

Your issue comes from the fact that `requests`' array type got somewhat altered by your `useEffect()`.

I suggest doing this instead:

```
fetch("http://localhost/scheduleapp/api/schedule/admin/requests", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setRequests(data))
```

As long as your `console.log(requests)` doesn't display a proper `array` (yours seems to be an object) then your issue would persist.

P.S. Since `GET` is the default method for `fetch`, I believe that specifying it on `requestOptions` isn't needed.